# Is there an excuse for a 20ft Cat6 Ethernet cable to have 36μH on all wires?

Tags: ethernet, cables, wire, rj45

I was just measuring the inductance of the 20ft (6m) Cat 6 Ethernet cable I just bought. I'm aware that 525 nH/m is what's expected for each wire, so that ought to have been 3.15μH. I've measured consistently a 36μH inductance for all the wires, which is 10 times what's expected. Is there an excuse for this??

Comment: What meter are you using to measure? Is the cable terminated? What exactly are you measuring... As in how are you hooking up your instrument?

Comment: A schematic of your measurement setup may be relevant.

Comment: End to end terminated by a female RJ-45 connector. The pins of the female RJ-45 have been spread out such that they can be clipped on by clip probes that are plugged in to a LC100-A L/C meter. Calibration is done before a cable is measured. On calibration, the probes themselves are shorted and then zero-ed  (with the Zero button on the LC meter). Simple as that.

Comment: what do you measure if you short the leads of whatever you are using to measure (LCR meter?)

Comment: It shows "0.000uH", which I take the lowest it can go for the lowest scale it can measure.

Comment: And is the cable laid out straight, or coiled?

Comment: 525 nH/m is the mutual inductance of two wires in a pair, which is the interesting bit for using it as a transmission line. This figure has nothing to do with the inductance of a single wire in your cable.

Comment: It's coiled and when I stretched it out, it's still 9.6uH.

Comment: Let me remind you that you have come here to ask a large community of *volunteers* for help with a technical issue. We expect that you will communicate in a professional and respectful manner, which will also get you the best results. Sarcastic, insulting and rude comments -- as well as *ad-hominum* attacks -- will not be tolerated.

Comment: "when I stretched it out, it's still 9.6uH" - Shape matters. Coiled into 6 turns (318mm diameter) it should be ~24uH. Stretched out in a circle (1.91m diameter), ~9.4uH.  Stretched out in an oblong until the sides meet, ~3uH. http://electronbunker.ca/eb/InductanceCalc.html

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're actually measuring a **lumped** inductance *for a single wire* with your LC meter, whereas the 525 nH/m spec is a **distributed** parameter *for a twisted pair* of the CAT6 cable acting as a transmission line. Both magnitudes are unrelated.

Take a look at the [telegrapher's equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations) and the transmission line model below:

[image: Transmission line model]

OTOH, the [calculated self-inductance](https://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/wire-inductance) of single a AWG24 20ft straight wire is 12 uH, quite close to your 9.6 uH measure.

Comment: I believe that model only applies when the transmission cable has been terminated when in use. I believe that my LC meter does not add an appreciable Gdx, as that would filter out the higher frequencies. Cdx, sure, as I believe that's how it forms the LC tank, measured against the crystal oscillator.

Comment: CAT6 cable is specified up to 250 MHz and 100m. The wavelength at 250 MHz in a transmission line of that kind (propagation velocity 68%) is 0,816 m << 6 m < 100m . Clearly, the manufacturer is specifying those 525 nH/m as a distributed parameter of the cable as a transmission line. The distributed parameters are intrinsical to the transmission line, and doesn't depend on load or source. You're measuring something completely different and unrelated to the 525 nH/m spec. The spec is *per twisted pair* whereas, as far as I've understood, you are measuring each of the 8 wires end-to-end.

Answer (score 3):

If you are measuring inductance between (say) the blue wire at one end and the blue wire at the other end, this is *not* what is specified in the data sheet, and not the parameter of interest for a transmission line.

What you need to do is to take one end of the cable, and short blue to blue-stripe.  (or any other individual pair).  Then from the other end, measure the inductance between those two wires.  Do this at a measurement frequency below such that the cable stub is < lambda/20 -- say below 1 MHz for a 20 foot section of cable.

If you do this, you should get an answer similar to the specified value.

You can now remove the short-circuit and measure capacitance in the same way, and use that to calculate the characteristic impedance.

Comment: Really can't change the frequency for measuring the inductance, that's fixed in the LC meter, I believe. Should I then simply just short the pairs and measure the inductance? You really should "Yeah, do it that way!" So I'd be more convinced.

Comment: This really ISN'T what I meant when I googled "series inductors".

Comment: Yes, you should just do it.  Unless you are using a fancy LCR meter with configurable frequency it won't be > 1 MHz.  Probably in the 10 kHz range.